# One table can not be foreign key to others except one table

Tags: python, django, django-models

For example

```
class Room(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Visitor)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    capacity = models.ForeignKey(Capacity, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    floor = models.ForeignKey(Floor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    is_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_vip = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('')

    def __str__(self):
        return '№{0}'.format(self.number)


class Reserved(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Reserved Room {0}'.format(self.room)

class Busy(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
```

Table Room can not be connected to Tables Reserved and Busy at the same time. Room should be reserved or busy. Is there way put validation for this? 
I tried to use unique_together but if for fields of table

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to enforce this at DB level nor a simple way to do it in Django level. With your structure you should add some validation before creating (or modifying) both `Busy` and `Reserved`. Something like:

```
class Busy(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)

    def __save__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Reserved.object.filter(room=self.room).exists():
            raise RuntimeError('Trying to make a reserved room busy.')
        super(Busy, self).__save__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you are creating `Busy` and `Reserved` objects concurrently it's subject to race condition. I suggest to move room state into `Room` model itself and add some helper functions (something like in `room_manager.py` beside `models.py`) to change its state and make sure related models are created/modified in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure *at the database level* that you have one single "status" at a given time for a room is to have your relationship the other way round - with `Room` have a foreign key on whatever represents the status. To make this work you'll need to use either some form of model inheritance or django's "generic" relationship (which can be handy sometimes but are really not SQL-friendly).

Here's an example using the very simplest form of "model inheritance" (which is not actually inheritance at all):

```
class Status(models.Model):
    BUSY = 1
    RESERVED = 2
    TYPES = (
        (BUSY,"busy"),
        (RESERVED,"reserved")
    )
    type = models.CharField("Status type", max_length=10, choices=TYPES)
    # only used for reservations
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        # TODO : this should belong to `full_clean()`, 
        # cf the FineManual model's validation
        if self.type == self.RESERVED and not self.begin_date:
            raise ValueError("RESERVED statuses need a begin_date")
        super(Status, self).save(*args, **kw)




class Room(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
```

Note that this allows for a same status to be used for multiple rooms at the same time, which might be a problem too. Using a `OneToOneField` field instead might help on the Django side but will still be treated as a foreign key at the database level.